# Postgres not able to recover in replication mode

Tags: postgresql-9.1, disaster-recovery

Because of manual cleanup of WAL files, my DB is corrupted. PostGres is throwing this error :

```
2017-08-10 20:44:41.887 UTC 2661    LOG:  database system was interrupted; 
last known up at 2017-08-03 04:07:25 UTC

2017-08-10 20:44:42 INFO:   preparing to get xlog FROM: /ghostcache6/postgresql9.1/drupal_db_1/wal_incoming/192.168.44.167/00000021.history.??????????.gz  TO: pg_xlog/RECOVERYHISTORY

2017-08-10 20:44:42 INFO:   Skip processing '.history' file.

2017-08-10 20:44:42.040 UTC 2661    LOG:  starting archive recovery

2017-08-10 20:44:42 INFO:   preparing to get xlog FROM: /ghostcache6/postgresql9.1/drupal_db_1/wal_incoming/192.168.44.167/0000002100000FD2000000A1.??????????.gz  TO: pg_xlog/RECOVERYXLOG
2017-08-10 20:44:42 INFO:   SWITCH TO LIVE MASTER DB TRIGGERED
2017-08-10 20:44:42.048 UTC 2661    LOG:  could not open file "pg_xlog/0000002100000FD2000000A1" (log file 4050, segment 161): No such file or directory
2017-08-10 20:44:42.048 UTC 2661    LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
2017-08-10 20:44:42 INFO:   preparing to get xlog FROM: /ghostcache6/postgresql9.1/drupal_db_1/wal_incoming/192.168.44.167/0000002100000FD20000009F.??????????.gz  TO: pg_xlog/RECOVERYXLOG
2017-08-10 20:44:42 INFO:   SWITCH TO LIVE MASTER DB TRIGGERED
2017-08-10 20:44:42.055 UTC 2661    LOG:  could not open file "pg_xlog/0000002100000FD20000009F" (log file 4050, segment 159): No such file or directory
2017-08-10 20:44:42.055 UTC 2661    LOG:  invalid secondary checkpoint record
2017-08-10 20:44:42.055 UTC 2661    PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
2017-08-10 20:44:42.055 UTC 2660    LOG:  startup process (PID 2661) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2017-08-10 20:44:42.055 UTC 2660    LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

Thankfully i have backup of data folder, which i extracted in data folder back. But Postgres is still down with the same error. Can i run pg_resetxlog in this case? Please suggest.

Comment: So the above log is from which error -- from before the restore of the data folder, or after?

Comment: Its same even after extracting it.